# window.open ignoring the width/height parameters

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble getting a popup to open in a particular size.

Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/uHD6k/

The js i'm trying to use is:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com', 'toolbar = 0', 'scrollbars = 1', 'statusbar = 0', 'menubar = 0', 'resizable = 0', 'height = 500', 'width = 433');
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the options go in the same string param:

```
  $('.my-link').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    window.open('http://www.google.com', 'WindowName','toolbar = 0, scrollbars = 1, statusbar = 0,     menubar = 0, resizable = 0, height = 500, width = 433');
  });
```

Comment: Actually, the window name cannot have any blank spaces inside: `'windowName'`

Answer (score 1):

Use this syntax

```
  $('.my-link').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      window.open(
       /* Url */
       'http://www.google.com', 
       /* Window Name */
       '', 
       /* Options */
       'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,...,height=500,width=433');
  });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uHD6k/1/

`window.open` accepts `url`, `windowName` and `options` as arguments.
Options are defined as a comma-separated single string.

Further reference available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open)

Answer (score 1):

Separate `string`(not arguments) with comma https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open

To example:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com', 'My window', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,height=500,width=433');
```